# How to change categorical variables in a for loop using a list with variable to change

Tags: python, pandas, categories, pandas-loc

I would like to simplify the number of categories for one variable. The piece of code below is working:

```
df.loc[(df['category'] == 'cat1')|(df['category'] == 'cat2')|(df['category'] == 'cat3')|...|(df['category'] == 'catn'),'category'] == 'other'
```

but I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
category_to_change = ['cat1','cat2','cat3',...,'catn']

for name in category_to_change:
    df.loc[(df['category'] == name),'category'] == 'other'
```

(this doesn't work)

Any ideas how to do?

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset and your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you provide extra code when asking a question, typically the code to create the dataframe, this helps to test suggestions.
This code should work :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'rat']})
df['category'] = df['category'].replace(['cat', 'dog'], 'other')
```

All occurrences of `cat` or `dog` are replaced by `other`.

Comment: @Pierre If this answers your question, please mark my response as 'Answer'